# Why can't I authenticate my SSH connection in Mathematica?

Tags: command-line, networking

I'm trying to SSH into my [Cyberpower PDU41001](https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/product/pdu/switched/pdu41001/), which is connected to my computer via Ethernet cable. My computer runs Windows 10. I have enabled SSH communication on the device by logging into the IP address that I assigned to it and configuring my port 22 for SSH.

At first I thought that simply telling Mathematica to connect to the IP address of my device and entering my computer log-in credentials would work. However, Mathematica kept returning an error that my credentials were wrong, even though they weren't.

I am able to SSH into the device from the shell using my credentials (not even needing a private key). I had to force my system to accept one of their offered cipher types - but after I did that, it worked. My credentials still aren't being accepted in Mathematica however.

Here's my code below. This should be enough to establish the connection. I'm using a private key file, it shouldn't have to ask for a password.

```
RemoteConnect[
  IPAddress["XXX.XXX.XX.XX"], 
  Authentication -> <|
     "Username" -> "Darren", 
     "SSHKey" -> File["C:\\Users\\darren\\.ssh\\id_rsa"] |>
]
```

What could be the reasons why Mathematica would reject me from my SSH network even when I'm using a private key and entering my correct credentials?

Comment: Using remote = RemoteConnect["192.168.1.140", "bashuser"] (+) Works fine for me. (+) https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1789287 Says with version 12 is broken. (+) I am on version 12.1 (+) Else, I often have to update /etc/hosts to add addresses of "who is connecting." (+) Try working with RSA key setups, then set up the key token, is my recommendation.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1989803).

Comment: Thanks @prog9910 I'll go down that route. Not sure what the discussion in your link is saying.. Is it saying that it is now impossible to connect to a specific IP address using Mathematica 12?

Comment: Contact Wolfram support, your best bet. Though they'll no doubt claim, your firewall is blocking your port or such.

Comment: @prog9910 that is exactly what they have claimed, but they are looking further into it for me now.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to Mathematica. Turns out the function they use for SSH tunneling is still an "experimental" function that they're working on. I'm able to do this tunneling from other programs so I'm just left to assume that it's a Mathematica problem :/